# PHP: Delete values from nested arrays

Tags: php

I am extracting duplicated values from nested arrays. I would like to delete these extraceted items from the $bigarray. would you give me some ideas...?

```
$bigarray = array(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    "430" => array('milk', 'turky', 'apple'),
    "433" => array('milk', 'apple', 'orange', 'england'),
    "444" => array('milk', 'apple', 'orange', 'spain')
);
$intersected = null;
foreach ($bigarray as $arr) {
  $intersected = $intersected ? array_intersect($arr, $intersected) : $arr;
  if (!$intersected) {
    break; // no reason to continue
  }
}


foreach ($intersected as $inter){
  foreach ($bigarray as $arr) { 
    foreach ($arr as $value=>$key) {
      if ($key ==  $inter){
        unset($arr[$value]);
      }
    }
  //print_r($arr);
  }
}
print_r($bigarray );
```

Comment: saying what's wrong with your sample code would be a good way to start...

Comment: yes i"m extracting duplicates, but not deleting them. I would like to extract and delete them from the original arrays.

Comment: Once you know what the duplicates are (`$intersected` after the loop exits), you take that result and go back to the original arrays and delete those values.

Comment: I'M doing it like that but nothing is happening...>foreach ($clauses as $arr) {foreach ($arr as $value) {
if($value == "Orange"){unset($value);}
}print_r($arr);}

Comment: `$value` in that context is a COPY of whatever's in the array. You need to refer to the original array: `unset($clauses[$key1][$key2])`.

Comment: Thank you, i finally understand what you've meant. I've got it now. THanks so much...

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [array_merge](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) as it will merge 2 arrays together and only keep one duplicate. From the manual:

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays
>   contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original
>   value, but will be appended.

Sounds like homework and the question isn't very clear so that is all I can provide for now.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
foreach($bigarray as $id => $arr)
    $bigarray[$id] = array_unique($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understood your question, but using array_unique() in your array I've got the following output:

```
array(1) {
  [430]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "milk"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "turky"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "Apple"
  }
}
```

Maybe this could be a way of acchieving what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
function array_unique_nested($arr=array(),$matched=array(),$cm=false){
foreach($arr as $i=>$v){
if (is_array($v)) {$arr[$i]=array_unique_nested($v,$matched,false);
$matched=array_unique_nested($v,$matched,true); continue;}
if (in_array($v,$matched)) {unset($arr[$i]);continue;}
$matched[]=$v;}
if ($cm) return $matched;
else return $arr;}
```

In case that doesn't work, this code snippet from http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php should do the trick.

```
if( !function_exists( 'array_flat' ) )
{
    function array_flat( $a, $s = array( ), $l = 0 )
{
    # check if this is an array
    if( !is_array( $a ) )                           return $s;

    # go through the array values
    foreach( $a as $k => $v )
    {
        # check if the contained values are arrays
        if( !is_array( $v ) )
        {
            # store the value
            $s[ ]       = $v;

            # move to the next node
            continue;

        }

        # increment depth level
        $l++;

        # replace the content of stored values
        $s              = array_flat( $v, $s, $l );

        # decrement depth level
        $l--;

    }

    # get only unique values
    if( $l == 0 ) $s = array_values( array_unique( $s ) );

    # return stored values
    return $s;

} # end of function array_flat( ...
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array_unique($array,[, int $sort_flags] function.  if you don't specify the optional sort_flag, the function will compare values converting everything to string. if you have values other than string in the array, you can specify sort_flag to be one of the following values

```
SORT_REGULAR - compare items normally (don't change types)
SORT_NUMERIC - compare items numerically
SORT_STRING - compare items as strings
SORT_LOCALE_STRING - compare items as strings, based on the current locale.
```

Example from PHP.net

```
         $input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
         $result = array_unique($input);
         print_r($result);
```

for more information refer 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php